# In catch(e) block, console.log(e.message) does not work with some error messages

Tags: javascript

In catch(e) block, console.log(e.message) does not work with some error messages.
But it works with some error messages.

This works:

```js
try {
  throw new Error('Incomplete data: no name');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}

// Incomplete data: no name
```

This does not work:

```js
try {
  throw new Error('Error');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

Why?

I'm using Google Chrome 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build).

---

In my Chrome, the result is as follows.
This is a copy of what is displayed on the console.

```
try {
  throw new Error('Incomplete data: no name');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}

VM345:4 Incomplete data: no name
undefined
try {
  throw new Error('Error');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
undefined
try {
  throw new Error('Incomplete data: no name');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}

VM361:4 Incomplete data: no name
undefined
```

Sorry for not uploading screenshot.
I'm new to Stack Overflow, so it seems to be limited.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Why it "does not work"? I'm using Chrome 74.0.3729.108, and it prints "Error" as excepted (it's what you passed as the error message).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3wamojrL/ same here, can you share the console log screenshot

Comment: I've tried on Chrome 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build, 64-Bit Win) and it works just as expected.

Comment: "does not work" means that it print nothing.
It seems like "console.log(e.message)" is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to see console.log(e.message) by changing the profile of Google Chrome.

Secret mode and disabling the extensions had no effect.

For now, this is OK.
Thank you.